# O EcmaScript 6 é suportado pelos browsers atuais?

Tags: javascript, front-end, navegador-de-internet, ecmascript-6

Os recursos do EcmaScript 6 disponíveis no JavaScript já podem ser utilizados de forma que seja suportada pelos browsers atuais? Gostaria de saber se essa versão já é suportada como um todo (e não somente funcionalidades específicas dela).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Suporte de Navegador**

> O **ECMAScript 3** é totalmente **suportado** em **todos os navegadores**.
>
> O **ECMAScript 5 (2009)** é totalmente **suportado** em **todos os navegadores modernos** . **Observação**: O **Internet Explorer 9 não suporta ECMAScript 5** `"use strict"`.
>
> O **ECMAScript 6 (ECMAScript 2015)** é totalmente **suportado** em **todos os navegadores modernos, menos no Internet Explorer.**
>
> O **ECMAScript 7 (ECMAScript 2016)** é suportado **apenas no Chrome e Opera.**
>
> **NOTA:** Observe sempre as **versões do browser** e quais **métodos** são **compatíveis** no **mesmo**.
>
> [W3SCHOOLS - FONTE](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_versions.asp)

**Mas e agora?** **Como faço para facilitar a minha vida e escrever um código seja em qual versão for do ecmascript e ter a compatibilidade na maioria dos navegadores e suas respectivas versões?**

Calma, como diz o **Chapolin**: `"Calma, não criemos panico.."`

Existem diversos **compiladores/transpiladores** e **bundlers Javascript de código aberto**. Abaixo citarei **dois (2)** deles e sua introdução.

**Webpack**

> Em sua essência, o **Webpack** é um **empacotador de módulos estáticos para aplicativos JavaScript modernos**. Quando o **webpack processa seu aplicativo**, ele cria internamente um **gráfico de dependência que mapeia todos os módulos de que seu projeto precisa e gera um ou mais pacotes configuráveis**.
>
> [WEBPACK - FONTE](https://webpack.js.org/)

**Babel**

> É um **toolchain** que é usado principalmente para c**onverter o código ECMAScript 2015+** em uma **versão compatível com versões anteriores do JavaScript** em **navegadores ou ambientes atuais e antigos**.
>
> [BABEL - FONTE](https://babeljs.io/)

**DICA:**

> Utilize o **Webpack**, pois com ele você consegue criar uma configuração para todos os seus **bundlers** e empacotamentos, inclusive você pode utilizar o Babel com ele.

Comment: Tem o TS (TypeScript)  que também é muito usado. _"todos os navegadores modernos, menos no Internet Explorer"_, discordo, IE deixou de ser "navegador moderno" há muito tempo

Comment: @Costamilam a questão da pergunta é ECMASCRIPT e não o super set do JAVASCRIPT (TYPESCRIPT)! Infelizmente não somos nós quem decidimos se o determinado navegador è moderno ou não, existe diversos assuntos para ser analisados pra podermos afirmar tal.. Eu também não gosto do IE, mas como Cientista da Computação eu tenho que me relacionar com todos os tipos de tecnologias, e o mais importante que vai ter cliente pedindo suporte no IE, então cuidado quando for manipular os scripts.

Comment: Calma, você comentou do babel e eu mencionei o TS só pra completar. O IE foi una piada, mas é verdade

Answer (score 4):

Quando eu quero saber se posso usar essa ou aquela funcionalidade e quais navegadores suportam e quais versões de navegadores suportam  costumo usar o site https://caniuse.com, por exemplo o Ecmascript6 que você falou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link com detalhes: https://caniuse.com/#search=es6

Answer (score 1):

Sim, o EcmaScript 6 já está sendo suportadas em *browsers* atuais.

Nesse contexto, definimos *browsers* modernos como as versões mais recentes do **Chrome**, **Firefox**, **Safari**, **Edge**, **Opera**, etc.

> Mas antes de usar um recurso específico, verifique a sua compatibilidade para certificar que o público alvo do seu projeto esteja sendo abrangido pelo suporte atual.
>
> Você pode usar *websites* como [a Tabela de Compatibilidade do EcmaScript](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) e [o Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=ecma%20script) para verificar suporte por *features* específicas de cada versão.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser, pode escrever seu código utilizando os recursos do ECMAScript 6 e mesmo assim suportar browsers antigos utilizando o [Babel](https://babeljs.io). Ele irá transformar seu código JavaScript de uma forma que os browsers antigos que você desejar entendam.

Você pode testar ele online [neste link](https://babeljs.io/repl). Ao abrir, ele vai estar marcado com o preset `es2015` por padrão.

Agora digite o código abaixo:

```js
function Teste() {
    let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1  ;

    if (a < 5) {
        return () => {
            console.log('A < 5');
        }
    } else {
        return () => {
            console.log('A >= 5');
        }
    }
}
```

Este código utiliza a keyword `let` e as [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

No lado direito, ele irá transformar o código para:

```js
"use strict";

function Teste() {
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

  if (a < 5) {
    return function () {
      console.log('A < 5');
    };
  } else {
    return function () {
      console.log('A >= 5');
    };
  }
}
```

Como pode ver, ele transformou o `let` em `var` e substituiu as as arrow functions por uma declaração de função normal.

Agora desmarque o preset `es2015` e habilite o **ENV preset**.  No campo **Browsers**, coloque `Firefox > 50` (ou seja, você está dizendo para ele transformar seu código de uma forma que as versões do Firefox maiores que 50 consigam interpretar).

Você irá perceber que o código continua idêntico, pois as versões do Firefox superiores a 50 suportam tanto o `let` quanto arrow functions.

Mude agora para `Firefox > 44`. Ele vai transformar o `let` em `var`, mas vai manter as arrow functions. Isso porque existe pelo menos uma versão do Firefox superior à 44 que ainda não suportava o `let`.

Recomendo dar uma pesquisada para se aprofundar mais e integrar o Babel à build de sua aplicação. Com ele, você pode utilizar as funcionalidades mais recentes da especificação ECMAScript sem deixar de dar suportes a browsers mais antigos.